# Why unable to acquire a semaphore immediately when another thread releases it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, semaphore, binary-semaphore

Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::binary_semaphore sema{ 1 };

int main()
{
    std::thread th([]
        {
            while (true)
            {
                sema.acquire();
                std::cout << "still hold\n";
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
                sema.release();
            }
        });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    std::cout << "try get\n";
    sema.acquire();
    std::cout << "semaphore get\n";

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10000));
}
```

Main thread should be able to obtain this semaphore immediately, because the std::thread quickly releases and reacquires the semaphore, and the main thread should be able to obtain this semaphore at this time.

But in fact the main thread does not get this semaphore immediately, but after the std::thread th loops many times, maybe only a few times, or maybe dozens of times.

I use msvc(c++20).

So why can't the main thread get it immediately?

Comment: It's a race condition. No guarantees.  In particular, no guarantees that a thread that has been politely patiently waiting will get priority over the other thread for acquisition.

Comment: std::thread releases semaphore but aquires it again on next iteration almost immediately.

Comment: You are expecting actions on different threads to be somehow sequenced. That is although both threads are simultaneoulsly trying to acquire the semaphore, for some reason the main thread should get it first. That is not how threads work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ threading and concurrency model does not guarantee "fairness" or "starvation freedom" in threads waiting for locks. Depending on the implementation, releasing the semaphore will mark the main thread as "ready to run", but won't necessarily hand the semaphore to the main thread, and won't necessarily immediately start it executing. And since the very next thing the `th` thread does is reacquire the semaphore, there's just no time for the main thread to grab it. (The main thread is in fact woken many times, but upon waking it sees that the semaphore has already been taken, and goes back to sleep.) It is possible to implement semaphores in a way which does guarantee fairness but it's more complicated and lowers performance, particularly on multi-core systems.

If you want to guarantee fairness in something like this, condition variables are a better approach, since they involve the thread explicitly yielding to one or each thread waiting to grab a particular mutex.

Incidentally, this aspect of semaphore implementations (threads may wake up and immediately go back to sleep) can become a serious problem if there are many threads waiting for the semaphore, since all of them get woken when the semaphore is released but at most one of them will get to grab it. This is known as the [thundering herd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem).

Comment: FYI: When I attempted to answer a similar question,somebody opined that a semaphore was supposed to obey a rule that they called "the weak semaphore property." They said, if one thread releases a permit to a semaphore when one or more other threads are blocked on it, then the next thread to win a permit from it _must_ be one of the waiting threads. I could not find that claim repeated anywhere else. I think it comes from misunderstanding an exercise in "The Little Book of Semaphores." But, y'know, internet.., misinformation... Maybe it will go viral any day now. Time will tell.